# JSON not firing API Key for Weather App

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, weather-api

I'm doing FCC weather app project using the Open WeatherMap API. I saw chrome is making issues serving geolocation over HTTP so I decided to use a user input for zip code instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // var zipCode = "54901";
  var key = "id=524901&APPID=24d9e7758a30704bbc766831845bcb5f";

  $(".btn").on("click", function(){
    var zipCode = document.getElementById("zipCode").value

    var api = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + zipCode + ",us" + "&" + key;  
    console.log("Before JSON"); //Works
    console.log(api); //Copy & Paste into browser works
    $.getJSON(api, function(data){
      console.log("JSON fired"); //Doesn't Log

    });  
  });  
});
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <h1>Weather App</h1>
  <input id="zipCode" type="text" placeholder="53154" />
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

User input gives a valid zipCode and everything works until my request for the JSON. Is this because my api isn't being concatenated correctly?

My codepen: https://codepen.io/dylanmparks/pen/LyRyOP?editors=1011

Comment: You forgot to include `http://` without that it tries to get a relative resource (on the same server as your page)

Comment: Needs to be `https://` to match Codepen

Comment: You're using a comma in your URL. If I'm not mistaken that's a reserved character and might cause issues. You'll also want to sanitize your user input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // var zipCode = "54901";
  var key = "id=524901&APPID=24d9e7758a30704bbc766831845bcb5f";
  
  $(".btn").on("click", function(){
    var zipCode = document.getElementById("zipCode").value
  
    var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + zipCode + ",us" + "&" + key;  
    console.log("Before JSON"); //Works
    console.log(api); //Copy & Paste into browser works
    $.getJSON(api, function(data){
      console.log("JSON fired => ", data); //Doesn't Log
    }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error){
      console.log('Error:', textStatus, error)
    });  
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>Weather App</h1>
  <input id="zipCode" type="text" placeholder="94040" />
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Tareq,

After running I get "Error:" "error" " "

Comment: I've done 54901, 53154, 12345, 90210. api url that logs works for each

Comment: I tried all of those and they are working fine. check your browser console for more info.

Comment: I did get this

GET https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=53154,us&id=524901&APPID=24d9e7758a30704bbc766831845bcb5f net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

but then I logged out of codepen and now your solution works. Thoughts on that?

Comment: I can see that codepin is over https and the call to the weather API is over http thus the AJAX call will be blocked by the browser. See this link for more info. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content